# How do I get jqxhr.responseText from HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This is my server side code

```
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent("FAIL FAIL"),
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
        };

        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
        return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => response);
```

This is my client side code using jquery

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'someurl',
            data: somevalues,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqxhr) {
                console.log(jqxhr);
            }
        });
```

But when I check using firebug, my jqxhr.responseText is "".
How do I retrieve "FAIL FAIL"?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var ajaxReult =   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'someurl',
        data: somevalues,
        success: function (data) {
           // console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqxhr) {
           // console.log(jqxhr);
        }
    }).responseText;
console.log(ajaxReult);
```

Comment: is your url is any cross-domain ??

Comment: yes, its cross domain..just found out something..if I debug using firefox, I got null, but if using IE, it shows..

Comment: You can't make call of POST type using AJAX in cross-domain services.
only GET calls are possible in cross-domain, yet it also should follow jquery call back mechanism in url. else should add data type to jsonp. hope reading this would help you more: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/